# Liquid Exception - Jekyll serve

Tags: ruby, windows, ssl, jekyll

I was trying to build a static site using poole and jekyll on my windows 10 system.
When I run the command `jekyll serve` I get the following error:

```
 Liquid Exception: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed in some_path/_posts/2016-01-02-example-content.md
jekyll 3.5.0 | Error:  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert access denied
```

I have tried using the cacert.pem fix , it didn't work.
Can you suggest any other alternatives or things I may have overlooked..?

Comment: Hard to say what's going on without more info. Can you check your basedomain as in config.yml? Also how does the content of this blog post look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an SSL certificate authentication error.

Try downloading the [GlobalSignRootCA.pem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/index.rubygems.org/GlobalSignRootCA.pem) file and placing it in the following path:

```
<Ruby installation directory>/lib/ruby/<version>/rubygems/ssl_certs
```

However, please note that **using Jekyll on Windows is not officially supported by the Jekyll team**. Therefore, you may continue to face errors on doing a `jekyll serve` on your system.

A workaround to this problem is to downgrade your Ruby to version 2.0.0 and Jekyll to version 2.4.0 (tested) and then use the [GlobalSignRootCA.pem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/index.rubygems.org/GlobalSignRootCA.pem) certificate fix as mentioned above to build your sites.

This is pretty well-covered in [this blog](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/).

Do remember that this is does not guarantee 100% error-free builds in the future since downgrading will kill support for a lot of frequently used gems.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already tried the certificate way but it didn't work. So worked around with a different jekyll template. It works smoothly with that. Guess some gems give this issue some don't, because that is what was changed in the other template, from the point of view of installation , usage and dependencies of various Gems.

Comment: @vutsuak Yeah, I too have been struggling with dependencies on Windows 10. Most templates and latest gems don't seem to work. I found that downgrading my Ruby and Jekyll and avoiding the Pygments highlighter did the trick for most cases.